# How to show line continuity in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

We can use `& _` and `_` as line continuation operator in vb.net. which one is the best practice?
Where i should use  `& _` and where to use `_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`& _` is used to perform continuation with concatenation , which is commonly used in the case of strings

Example :

```
  "This is " & _
  "sample string"
```

`_` is simple continuation operator, but it cannot be applicable in the case of strings

Example :

```
 Dim a As _
 String
```

Both can be used together as

```
 Dim sample As _
   String = "This is " & _
  "sample string"
```